# Confusing point of Laravel and implementing Entity Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, relation

I've used laravel eloquent quite a long time. Every second when I'm using eloquent relation, there is one or more confusing point that determining what kind of relation that I have to use (OneToOne, OneToMany, ManyToMany and its inverse...)

From what I understand, in laravel, there is `OneToMany Polymorphic` relation and in its document, the implementation has clear direction. `Video` and `Post` has many `Comment`. So, `Comment` morph to a `Video` or a `Post` and `Video` or `Post` morph (to) many `Comment`s. I get that. This is the situation that `Various type of "one" object` has `One type of "many" object`.

Lets suppose a.. `Chapter` has many `Section`s and `Column`s. This, from what I understand, is opposite situation. This one is that `One type of "one" object` has `Various type of "many" object`.

So, at this point, I can't decide what I have to do. Would you explain for me that how did you solve this confusing problem? Does Laravel Relation can't explain full situation?

---

Question Update .1

I have two tables named `Collection` and `Problem`.

In relational perspective, `Collection` has its child `Collection` and `Problem`.

For example, `CollectionA` has its child `Problem1`, `CollectionB`, `Problem2`, `Problem3` and `CollectionC`. Those five childrens has its order as written.

Since the children has order throughout two diffrent class, I think I cannot decouple them as seperate hasMany relations..

** To solve this problem, I've been using following idea.

`Collection` has many `CollectionItem`.

`CollectionItem` morphTo `Collection`|`Problem`.

This works find at this certain point, but I can't sure this is find practice..

Comment: In essence, your collections have `parent` and `child` collections. Any collection will have it's own `problems`. No? In which case, you might want to read up on parent-child relationships on the same model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like a simple pair of [One to Many relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many):

- A `Chapter` has many `Section`s
- a `Chapter` has many `Column`s

So, just define both relationships:

```
# Chapter.php

public function sections()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Section::class);
}

public function sections()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Column::class);
}
```

Of course, you can also define the [reverse of the relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) on each child model:

```php
# Section.php

public function chapter()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Chapter::class);
}
```

```php
# Column.php

public function chapter()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Chapter::class);
}
```

Comment: then what should I do when I have to ordering both section and column? When I do that, there are two fully decoupled table `section` and `column` that I cannot ordering them as childrens of `Chapter`..

Comment: @GatesPlan how should it work? [edit] your question adding details of your problem and your desired output.